# Get field where "exists" two certain rows

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following data structure:

```
field1         | field2
---------------+--------
something      | 2
something      | 1
anotherone     | 2
anotheranothe  | 1
```

I want to get all `field1` grouped by whenever there exists `field2` of "x" and "y".

If "x" is equal to 1 and "y" is equal to 2, then the result of the query should be "something", because another one only has "2" and anotheranothe only has "1". **something** is the only one which has 2 and 1.

Any idea on how to do this? I tried with `distinct` amongst others but failed

Comment: @wumm thanks for helping me with the format of the question. I'd love to understand why the downvotes if the questions are explicit ;)

Comment: WHERE ... IN (...) GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) = ...

Comment: The question was probably down voted because of the bad formatting and because you don't show any researches or code you tried yet.

Comment: @Strawberry would you please answer instead of the comment so I can give you your pointz!? :)))))

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a query like this:

```
select field1
from table t
group by field1
having sum(field2 = 1) > 0 and
      sum(field2 = 2) > 0;
```

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  These are often solved most flexibly using aggregation and the `having` clause.  Each condition in the `having` clause checks for one of the values.  The `> 0` ensures that it is there.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I see.  I misspelt `having`.